# How to manage self created error message instead of using default celebrate @hapi/joi code

Tags: joi, custom-errors, hapi, custom-error-handling

I have two files, one is api.js and other one is handler.js. For schema handling I am using celebrate module @hapi/joi

> On api.js I wrote only the API name
>
> On handler.js I wrote the API functionality.

```
api.js
//JOI Schema Validator Middleware.
router.use(celebrate({
    body: Joi.object().keys({
        post: Joi.string().max(10),
        userid: Joi.string(),
    })
}));

const handler = require('./handler');

router.post('/createpost', handler.createPost);

router.use(errors());

module.exports = router;
```

By this if error happens then i got the Response like this

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"child \"post\" fails because [\"post\" length must be less than or equal to 10 characters long]","validation":{"source":"body","keys":["post"]}}
```

I just want to Convert this error into my own format error i.e something like this

```
{error: true, status: 500, message: 'validation error', version: x.x.2}
```

The default joi error is generated through `router.use(errors());` this module. How I modify this?
Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

### TL;DR: Create your own 'errors()' function.

You have probably managed to change it by now, but just like me, I had the exact same issue and found this answerless thread.

Well, for future readers, celebrate errors() is nothing else than a function, more exactly, this one:

```js
(err, req, res, next) => {
  // If this isn't a Celebrate error, send it to the next error handler
  if (!isCelebrate(err)) {
    return next(err);
  }

  const {
    joi,
    meta,
  } = err;

  const result = {
    statusCode: 400,
    error: 'Bad Request',
    message: joi.message,
    validation: {
      source: meta.source,
      keys: [],
    },
  };

  if (joi.details) {
    for (let i = 0; i < joi.details.length; i += 1) {
      const path = joi.details[i].path.join('.');
      result.validation.keys.push(EscapeHtml(path));
    }
  }
  return res.status(400).send(result);
}
```

There, you can see the response object 'result' being declared and how it's done. So, to change the output of it, you have to **not use** errors() and **create your own** function to handle it.

So, I declared a new function:

```js
  private errorHandling = (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (isCelebrate(err)) {
        return res.send({
            statusCode: 400,
            message: err.joi.message
        });
    }
    
    return next(err);
  }
```

You can obviously change the above to suit your needs.

---

#### Update

Celebrate changed their error structure to a CelebrateError, now you need access the error details using:

```
  const errorBody = err.details.get('body'); // 'details' is a Map()
  const { details: [errorDetails] } = errorBody;
```

instead of the `err.joi`. The message property remains the same.

---

Then, instead of using `app.use(errors())` I used `app.use(this.errorHandling)`, and now I get the celebrate response formatted as I want to.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found out it can be solved 2 ways:

```
[Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
value: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('Value is required and has to be a text!')),
})
```

or

```
[Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
password: Joi.string().required().pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$')).min(8).label('Password').messages({
    'string.pattern.base': 'Your {#label} does not matche the suggested pattern',
    'string.base': `Your {#label} should match the suggested pattern`,
    'string.empty': `Your {#label} can not be empty`,
    'string.min': `Your {#label} has to be at least {#limit} chars`,
    'any.required': `Your {#label} is required`,
}),
```

})